# PHP post throws 404 error after submit

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

I am trying to make simple login system. But I encountered a problem with post method. Simple register.php file is not working:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    print('text');
}
?>

<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" required/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

After pressing a button it opens 404 error page.

I searched through dozens of similar questions but still got no solution. I'm working on localhost, PhpStorm 2016.3.2 and PHP7.0 and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: working at my end.Is this file have `.php` extension or not?

Comment: It has .php extension

Comment: test `phpinfo();`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/144dCNRf

Comment: What URL (full one please) do you see in a browser when it does not work?

Comment: localhost:63342/dbProject/LoginSystem/registration.php

Comment: that was after submit, before it is for example: http://localhost:63342/dbProject/LoginSystem/registration.php?_ijt=jcn534jms2e8uqe79fugjg1a6q

Comment: This is your problem. That hash is a secure mechanism for IntellIJ to make sure only YOU can view the page. The moment you post you lose this security hash and IntellIJ will give you a 404.

Comment: AFAIK that hash is for JS related stuff. It should not affect actual PHP. But yes -- you are using PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server. It's better if you use proper one -- Apache/nginx/IIS/etc -- try XAMPP or some another bundle for your OS if you cannot install or configure web server yourself.

Comment: Does it change something that i can open localhost:63342/dbProject/LoginSystem/registration.php in my browser (but still after submit, it opens 
localhost:63342/dbProject/LoginSystem/registration.php and there is 404)?

Comment: EDIT: I'm not losing my hash - I was using wrong version of the program. (One with action='registration.php')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:
It was built-in PhpStorm server's fault. It's not working when post method is used.

I'm using now Lampp and post works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's work. Are you start Xampp Server or Lampp Severr on your Ubuntu ? I think you forgot to start Server

Comment: Nope, in that case he would not get a 404.

Comment: I only added PHP interpreter in PhpStorm. I have never used Xampp/Lampp Servers. Should I start using it?

Comment: I never use PhpStorm, but I think you just start your server. It's ok. You can follow this site to know how to use it. 

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu-14-04-quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
echo $username;
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" required />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the action attribute to the form tag and see.. Here I have added index.php.. U can change it to the same file u r working on.. This might solve the problem.

```html
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" required/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The above example uses index.php. You are using a register.php file. If you open the URL using IntellIJ, does it show register.php in the URL or did IntellIJ rewrite the URL for you? What is the final URL?

Comment: yeah u have to change action="register.php" in your case

Comment: Yes, I chaged it.

Comment: Yes. I hope non-built-in-PhpStorm server will repair it - I'm trying to install it